# how to validate that two underscores are not together in regular expression

Tags: regex, validation

I have tried different regular expressions already but I am not sure how to have it catch one or more underscore. If are two together, must be invalid.

First word must be capital letter, then any character, the problem is underscore

I have this: `(^[A-Z])(\w{6,30} ?=*(_))`

Comment: Maybe a negative lookahead > `(^[A-Z])(\w{6,30} ?=*(_(?!_)))` or Just end string? It's hard to tell without sample data unfortunately =(. Btw, `\w` is **not** any character.

Comment: Good question! Can you provide an example of what you're trying to match to help clarify?

Comment: Do you want to check no double-underscores before the “=“, or after the “=“, or both ?

Comment: Actually I try to use a negative, but it doesn't work

Comment: For example, when i'm trying to put this " emma_3333312" could be posible, but instead of that i put "emma_ _3333312" with doble underscore, must be incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex may work for you with a negative lookahead condition:

```
^[A-Z](?![^_]*__)\w{6,30}$
```

`(?![^_]*__)` is a negative lookahead condition that fails the match if `__` appear anywhere after first capital letter.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DgwTmw/1/)

Comment: OHhhh yesss, 
it's just what I was looking for thanks

Comment: Hehe oh yes!!!! thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a pattern which is a word starting with a capital letter followed by some groups consisting of a single underscore and a word:

```
^[A-Z]\w{6,30}(_\w{6,30})*$
```